# How to Limit Number of connection to specific port in linux?

Tags: linux, firewall

I would like to limit number of connection to some ports.
for example:
I would like to allow just 2 connection for ports between 2300 to 2500 on my server.
But I don't know how can I do that using iptables.
Is there need additional software?
Any suggestion?

Comment: Sounds like an xy problem. Why a range of ports rather than just one, and why iptables? What problem are you trying to solve? ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem )

Comment: NO. I want to sell some service on my server for different people. But I want to restrict to share in public. I want to restrict only for 2 connection per port. So if person share it on public. it doesn't for more then 2 connection.

Comment: I can run that service multi time for different ports. but I can't put restriction from inside of that service. So I want to use firewall for that purpose.

Comment: So the limit is no more than 2 connections per port for ports between 2300 and 2500, rather than 2 connections in total? Can you not just use xinetd with an "instances" set to 2 rather than the default of unlimited?

Comment: No. It doesn't work. because I need to run multi time. but each time in different ports. so the only way to solve the limit the number of connection.

Comment: You can (in fact must) have multiple lines in the xinetd.conf file, one for each port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with *nftables*, using kernel >= 4.18 (tested here with kernel 5.3) and nftables >= 0.9.1 for its [connlimit](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NFT_CONNLIMIT.html)'s [count](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/?id=fe573574fcb2605bc9011c621f44654707180765) feature (and the *dynamic* flag used here). It's more flexible than [*iptables*'s connlimit](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#connlimit) because you can choose, when creating the [meter](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Meters) [set](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Sets#Named_sets), the selector(s) and masks on which the limit will be applied, while only a few possible selectors (not including port) exist for *iptables*, which would have probably required to have one rule per port.

Here's the adaptation of the [wiki example](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Meters#Doing_connlimit_with_nft), except we track incoming TCP ports instead of outgoing IP addresses to address OP's question. Any TCP connection to the same local port between 2300 and 2500 after having already established two, will be rejected with TCP RST. I understand *ct state new* is just an optimization to avoid having to try and add from packet path a new element for *every* incoming packet in the connection rather than just the first.

*nft* rules file to load with `nft -f`:

```
flush ruleset

table ip my_filter_table {
       set my_connlimit {
               type inet_service
               size 65535
               flags dynamic
       }

       chain my_input_chain {
               type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
               tcp dport 2300-2500 ct state new add @my_connlimit { tcp dport ct count over 2 } counter reject with tcp reset
       }
}
```

Matching connections will create entries in *my_connlimit*: the selector entries dynamically created, rather than the current counts (which are handled by *connlimit* using *conntrack*'s entries). For this specific case setting the set's size to 2500-2300+1=201 would probably have been enough. The added elements will disappear automatically (at least on kernel 5.3) when there's no associated count anymore (ie: all connections on this port were closed). Example after having established one or two connections on port 2301:

```
# nft list set ip my_filter_table my_connlimit
table ip my_filter_table {
        set my_connlimit {
                type inet_service
                size 65535
                flags dynamic
                elements = { 2301 ct count over 2  }
        }
}
```

UDP would have worked the same except conntrack will usually timeout the entry between 30s and 120s (was 180s before) after last activity since there's no actual connection. It's also possible to use a [*concatenation*](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Concatenations) instead of a simple *set* as meter, for example to limit this *per server's IP plus port* rather than just *per port* for a server having multiple IPs, like this:

```
flush ruleset

table ip my_filter_table {
       set my_connlimit {
               type ipv4_addr . inet_service
               size 65535
               flags dynamic
       }

       chain my_input_chain {
               type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
               tcp dport 2300-2500 ct state new add @my_connlimit { ip daddr . tcp dport ct count over 2 } counter reject with tcp reset
       }
}
```

Note: to avoid counting local connections in the meter, connections going through the *lo* device should be bypassed. For example:

```
# nft insert rule ip my_filter_table my_input_chain iif lo accept
```